# Find contained string in a string and get it's ending index value

Tags: c#, string

I'm trying to store unknown amount of specific strings inside a string but I want to get it's index so I can check it again. For example:

```
List<string> values = new List<string>();
int num;
string line = "/hello/1 /a/sdhdkd asjs /hello/2 ajhsd asjskjd skj /hello/s sajdk /hello/3 assdsfd hello/4";
```

And I want to store: `/hello/1`, `/hello/2`, `/hello/3` and `/hello/4` but NOT hello/s because it's different pattern (Not number) in a string List but I don't know how...

What I think is this:

//detect a common pattern between them

```
if(line.Contains("/hello/")
```

How can I know which is the position of the last "/" found in "/hello/" (In `line` it would be `line[6]`) so I can do this: `if(int.TryParse(line[7], num))`

if this TryParse returns true, it would store `values.Add("/hello/"+line[7]);`
The value after "/" won't be higher than 9 or negative (Example: /hello/34 or /hello/-23)

And then an auxiliar string would be what is AFTER this:

```
string aux = "";
for(int i=index_value; i<line.Length; i++) aux+= line[i]; //Where index_value would be 7+1
line = aux;
```

So now, line is:

```
" /a/sdhdkd asjs /hello/2 ajhsd asjskjd skj /hello/s sajdk /hello/3 assdsfd hello/4";
```

and I will make the search again, but what I am missing is how to get that index value so next time I make this search, my line would be:

```
" ajhsd asjskjd skj /hello/s sajdk /hello/3 assdsfd hello/4";
```

after finding and saving "/hello/2"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a good place to use regular expressions (and that's not something I say often). For example:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var regex = new Regex(@"/hello/\d+\b");
        var text = "/hello/1 /a/sdhdkd asjs /hello/2 ajhsd " 
            + "asjskjd skj /hello/s sajdk /hello/3 assdsfd hello/4";

        foreach (Match match in regex.Matches(text))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} at {1}", match.Value, match.Index);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
/hello/1 at 0
/hello/2 at 24
/hello/3 at 66
```

(No `hello/4`, because it doesn't have a leading slash.)

If the `hello` shouldn't be hardcoded, you could use `new Regex(@"/\w+/\d+\b")` or something similar to allow all word characters in the slug.

Comment: Ohh didn't know about that of RegularExpressions in .NET lol Thanks! Works very fine!

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different approach. See if this helps -

```
string line = "/hello/1 /a/sdhdkd asjs /hello/2 ajhsd asjskjd skj /hello/s sajdk /hello/3 ";
string[] lineParts = line.Split(' ');

int helloPartIndex;
int helloSuffix;
foreach (string linePart in lineParts)
{
      if (linePart.StartsWith("/hello/"))
      {
           helloPartIndex = line.IndexOf(linePart); //This is the index of the part in the entire line
           string[] helloParts = linePart.Split('/');
           if(helloParts != null && helloParts.Length >0)

           if (int.TryParse(helloParts[2], out helloSuffix))
           {
                  // Do stuff when the hello suffix is integer
           }
           else
           {
                 // This is where you have to deal with /hello/s and so on
           }
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `Contains()`, you're looking to use `String.IndexOf (String, Int32)`, as it can get index of "Hello/" starting from specific index. The idea is to keep track of current index and advance it step by step.

```
void Main()
{   
    var line = @"/hello/1 /a/sdhdkd asjs /hello/2 ajhsd 
               asjskjd sk /hello/s sajdk /hello/3 assdsfd hello/4";
    var searchString = "/hello/";
    var index = 0;

    var values = new List<int>();

    while(index < line.Length && 
         (index = line.IndexOf(searchString, index)) != -1)
    {
        index += searchString.Length;
        if(index < line.Length &&
           Char.IsDigit(line[index]))
            values.Add((int)(line[index] - '0'));
    }   

    Console.WriteLine(values);
}
```